# How to apply jQuery for appended (added, befored) divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Why isn't jQuery being applied to dynamically created elements?

Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5RuC/19/

When you click on regular cell it changes the border.
When you click on generated cells nothing happens.
Why? And what do I need to change to get generated cells working?

1. Create a board:

   ```
   function generateBoard() {
    var generatedDiv = "<div class='board'>";
        /* ... 
            generatedDiv += "<div class='cell'>&nbsp;</div>";
           ...
        */
    generatedDiv += "</div>"
    return generatedDiv
   }

    $("#generate").click(function() { 
        generatedDiv = generateBoard();
        $("#board").after(generatedDiv);
    });
   ```
2. Append div:

   ```
   generatedDiv = generateBoard();
   $("#menu").after(generatedDiv);
   ```
3. Change border on click:

   ```
    $(".cell").click(function() { 
        console.log(this);
        $(this).css("border", "3px solid black");
    });
   ```

It doesn't work for automatically generated content. In pure HTML:

```
<div class="cell"></div>
```

Just works. In generated board - just not :( Once again here is jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5RuC/19/

How to make it for  `$(".cell").click` to work fine in generated board?

Comment: Updated your's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/Y5RuC/21/) to a working version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` version:

```
$("body").on("click", ".cell", function(){
        console.log(this);
        $(this).css("border", "3px solid black");
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/Y5RuC/21/)

Jquery on [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: `live` shouldn't be used even with jQuery < 1.7. Use `delegate` instead.

Comment: @JamesAllardice. Not quite. Added all versions functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either the `delegate()` or `live()` methods for attaching events, which will work on all matched elements current or future. `delegate()` is the preferred method.

Or if you're using jQuery 1.7+ you can use `on()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/))